# Prevent resubmit a form and struts

Tags: forms, form-submit, struts-1

I have two jsp page: page1.jsp with a form and page2.jsp which displays a message to tell the user if the record insert happened or not.

If the form is successfully submitted and the user refreshes the page2, another insert happens.

I wouldn't to use a session variable, and setting a request attribute in the page2 doesn't resolve the issue (it seems to not work).

Comment: You should be using the post-redirect-get pattern.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thank you, how could I maintain the request after redirect in struts 1 (via struts-config.xml and the mapping.findForward in the Action)?

Comment: @DaveNewton: if you write an answer, I'll accept it,

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this:

> From `page1.jsp` set a request attribute, when control reaches to
>   `page2.jsp` check for that request attribute if it is there redirect the
>   control to same page2.jsp. In this way when control is redirected to
>   same or other resource, previous request and response objects are no
>   more there(i.e. both request and response object will destroy because
>   HTTP is stateless protocol) And like this after redirection there will
>   be no data related to previous request and on refreshing the page2.jsp it
>   will not repeat the previous task.

I am not sure but in one of my application I used the same for the purpose. Let me know if anyone has a better alternative.